# Looping through simple array to echo results in html

Tags: php

I have looked at various questions explaining this and try applying but I still can't get this to work.

I have a array that i am getting from my function.

```
function get_cat_names(){
global $user;
global $mysqli;
$querytotalcat="SELECT DISTINCT category FROM tbl_user_tmp where user = '$user' AND category IS NOT NULL";
$result_totalcat=$mysqli->query($querytotalcat);
while($row = $result_totalcat->fetch_array()){
    extract($row);
    $categories[] = array($category);
}
return $categories;
```

}

Then on my html page im doing this

```
<ul id="tasks" class="item-list">

 <?php 
 $categories = get_cat_names();

 foreach($categories as $cat){
 debug_to_console($cat);
 echo '<li class="item-orange clearfix">';
 echo '<label class="inline">';
 echo '<span class="lbl">'.$cat .'</span>';
 echo '</label>';
 echo '</li>';
 }

 ?>
 </ul>
```

I get output on my list but its Array for every item.

However on my debug_to_console function i get the correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$categories[] = array($category);
```

to

```
$categories[] = $category;
```

your adding an extra dimension for no good reason